# Does the tag equation-solving contain too much?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I didn't know that questions about `NDSolve` can also be tagged as [equation-solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation-solving) until I read the *about* of it today. 6 functions are mentioned in the *excerpt* and 3 more in the *about*.

[equation-solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation-solving), don't you feel tired?

More specifically, I think questions about `DSolve` and `NDSolve` need not to be contained in this tag. Solving differential equations is not that same as the others. If a equation can be solved by `Solve`, then it's likely to be solved by `Reduce`, `FindInstance`, `FindRoot` in some way, but `DSolve` and `NDSolve` aren't the case, and from what I've seen, most users tend to not tag questions about differential equations with [equation-solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation-solving).

We can even change its name into something like… [non-differential-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-differential-equations)?

Anyway, I think this tag need some improvement. What do you think?

Comment: Well, `DSolve`/`NDSolve` can also solve DAEs, so I think the distinction is perhaps not as sharp as you suggest. My POV is that if the question is mainly about solving a particular system of equations, then [tag:equation-solving] is perfectly appropriate, even if it might be rather too broad if not narrowed by the presence of additional tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[non-differential-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/non-differential-equations) is a bit too much like "everything-else", which is worse than what we have now. Tags are not necessarily exclusive containers... I tend to see them more as labels. A picture labeled "rose" can also have the labels "red" and "flower". As the tag wiki explains, if you have a DE, use [equation-solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation-solving)+[differential-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-equations); if you're solving Diophantine equations, use [equation-solving](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/equation-solving)+[diophantine-equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diophantine-equations) and so on.

There is definitely room for improvement in our tagging system and I welcome and appreciate any and all suggestions. Several low use tags, useless tags, etc. need to be culled and hundreds of questions properly retagged, but it is a big task. However, I'm just not sure that the present question is actually all that big of a problem to warrant renaming/retagging. If you disagree, please edit the question to provide concrete examples.